# How to use ldap authentication with grails 2.2.1

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-ldap

How to connect grails application with LDAP server running on localhost? How to authenticate a user using ldap? i am using grails version 2.2.1

Comment: Install the [Spring Security Core](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) and [Spring Security LDAP](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ldap) plugins and follow the documentation to configure them.

Answer (score 2):

Grails spring security plugin provides ldap authentication.

Refer : http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core

LDAP authentication is done with : http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ldap

`BuildConfig.groovy` will be looks like

```
plugins {
    . . .

    compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC4'
    compile ':spring-security-ldap:2.0-RC2'

    . . .
}
```